# jQuery: converting a select box value and text to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert a select box value and text to an object, below is what I have tried. The result is not like what I wanted, any ideas?

Thanks

HTML code:

```
<select id="district">
     <option selected="" value="-1"> All </ option>
     <option value="44"> Kowloon Tong </ option>
     <option value="46"> Yau Yat Tsuen </ option>
     <option value="47"> Ho Man Tin </ option>
     <option value="101"> Fei Ngo Shan </ option>
     <option value="133"> Beacon Hill </ option>
</ select>
```

JS code:

```
var a = []
$('#district option').each(function () {
    var a1 = parseInt($(this).attr('value'))
    var a2 = $(this).text()

    var b = {
        a1: a2
    }
    a.push(b)
})
console.log(a)
```

Result:

```
[
    Object {
        a1 = " all regions "
    },
    Object {
        a1 = " Kowloon Tong "
    },
    Object {
        a1 = " Yau Yat Chuen "
    },
    Object {
        a1 = " Ho Man "
    },
    Object {
        a1 = " Fei Ngo Shan "
    },
    Object {
        a1 = " Beacon Hill "
    }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
    Object {
        44 = " all regions "
    },
    Object {
        46 = " Kowloon Tong "
    },
    Object {
        47 = " Yau Yat Chuen "
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
 var b = {};
 b[a1]=a2;
 a.push(b)
```

Reason is that you need to set up the keys for the object. if you use `a1` as property name in the object literal it itself becomes the key not the value of it. So you can use `obj[key]` literal.

#### Full Code

```
var a = []
$('#district option').each(function () {
    var a1 = parseInt(this.value);
    var a2 = $(this).text();
    var b = {};
    b[a1] = a2;
    a.push(b)

})
console.log(a)
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sd6EW/)

Answer (score 4):

```
var a = []
$('#district option').each(function () {
    var a1 = parseInt($(this).attr('value'))
    var a2 = $(this).text()

    var b = {};
    b[a1] = a2
    a.push(b)
})
console.log(a)
```